# Permission denied to execute Jboss on Intellij

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, jboss, permission-denied

I'm trying to run Jboss Server on Intellij and I don't understand where I need to give this permission, because I've already gave permission for java and standalone.sh.

Can someone help me, please?

> /home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/standalone.sh: 1: eval: /home/henrique/.jdks/azul-11.0.11: Permission denied

[standalone.sh permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wJWX.png)

[java permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2nJ7.png)

full log on start

```
/home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/standalone.sh

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2

  JAVA: /home/henrique/.jdks/azul-11.0.11

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms1303m -Xmx12g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true 

=========================================================================

/home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/standalone.sh: 1: eval: /home/henrique/.jdks/azul-11.0.11: Permission denied
```

Thanks!

Comment: By what user do you run the IDE? How did you install the JDK? Try re-install the JDK or use another JDK installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions:

1- First one to run using `sudo`

```
sudo sh /home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/standalone.sh
```

2- Second one to create a group for webserver and give the right permission to that group then add jboss to that group if there is a username to jboss or  add all under `jboss-eap-7.2` directory

i.e

```
sudo groupadd webserver
sudo chgrp -R webserver /home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2/
sudo chmod -R g=rwx /home/henrique/jboss-eap-7.2/
```

Comment: run with sudo, i have the same problem =/

Comment: @Henrique try to use second solution